# PHP accessing element in array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

i have an array that looks like that :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => Classify
            [classification] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => negative
                            [p] => 0.0650294
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => positive
                            [p] => 0.934971
                        )

                )

            [text] => Understanding if a text is positive or negative is easy for humans, but a lot harder for computers. We can “read between the lines”, get jokes and identify irony. Computers aren’t quite there yet but the gap is quickly closing in.
        )

)
```

How can i access the `positive` & `negative` value?

Comment: yeah i know it's answer from an API so i can't do much about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple elements in the top-most array, you'd have to parse each element:

```
foreach($item in $array)
    foreach($classification in $item['classification'])
        echo $classification['class'];
```

Comment: In that case, you can remove the first line, and just replace the second line, with this one: foreach($classification in $array[0]['classification'])

Answer (score 2):

The outer array is numerically indexed (having one element, an associative array), and those two values are components of the array elements contained in the array `classification`, which is also numerically indexed, whose elements are associative arrays.

```
// By iteration, assuming an unknown number of classifications
foreach ($array[0]['classification'] as $classification) {    
  echo $classification['class'];
  echo $classification['p'];
}

// Or direct access to the elements
echo $array[0]['classification'][0]['class']; // negative
echo $array[0]['classification'][0]['p']; // 0.0650294
echo $array[0]['classification'][1]['class']; // positive
echo $array[0]['classification'][1]['p']; // 0.934971
```

Answer (score 2):

`$array[0]['classification'][0]['p']` and `$array[0]['classification'][1]['p']` to access the double values.

`$array[0]['classification'][0]['class']` and `$array[0]['classification'][1]['class']` to access the 'positive' and 'negative' strings

Comment: It's an array, not an object.

Comment: Yeah. Thats why I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
print $arr[0]['classification'][0]['class'];
print $arr[0]['classification'][1]['class'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print $array[0]['classification'][0]['class'];
print $array[0]['classification'][1]['class'];
```

provided it's always the same amount of classifications...